# Command Path issue with serverspec, need steps for ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, serverspec

I've installed serverspec on my server
command to execute serverspec is serverspec-init.
But this is working for me only when I do the full command path.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/serverspec-2.41.5/bin/serverspec-init
but when i do
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"

serverspec-init command works fine

I need to update these steps into ansible
can anyone help me out to do ansible steps

Thankyou

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what's going on here. In which path exactly is the `serverspec-init` command actually installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an environment to both `command:` and `shell:`, and likely a bunch of other modules

```yaml
- command: serverspec-init
  environment:
     PATH: "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
```

Comment: Then please mark the answer as accepted so it will let others know it is a solution that worked for you